# How can I install Zephir on Ubuntu?

Tags: php-extension, zephir

I would like to install Zephir on my Ubuntu machine.

The goal is to convert some of my existing code into a PHP extension, in order to get the benefits of faster execution.

Any pointers are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note Zephir is currently in Alpha stage and therefore bugs can be expected.

You need to have certain packages installed:

[json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)
[re2c](http://re2c.org/)

In the command line type:

```
sudo apt-get install libjson0 libjson0-dev libjson0-dbg
sudo apt-get install re2c
```

Once you have the required packages installed, you can generate the parser as follows:

```
./generate
```

Compile the extension (this is your code):

```
./zephir
```

The code produced is placed in ext/, there you can perform the standard compilation:

```
cd ext/
sudo ./install
```

Comment: How i can setup 'zephir' on windows machine. I've a windows-7 machine of 64 bit.

Comment: @Nikolaos, Is Zephir still in Alpha?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes still in alpha but I have been using it for quite a while and so far (for whatever I am using it) is working fine :)

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos : is it still working. The steps seems to be not working now in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Install zephir in Ubuntu..

You need download Zephir-master from https://github.com/phalcon/zephir

You nedd download json-c from https://github.com/json-c/json-c

1) sudo apt-get install gcc make re2c phpX phpX-json phpx-dev libpcre3-dev

2) Open folder Json-c

2.1) sh autogen.sh

2.2) ./configure

2.3) make && make install

3) Open folder zephir-master

3.1) ./install -c

4) zephir help for to test the correct installation